# How to pass variable from form to ajax in ASP.NET CORE 2.2

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core

I have page with an item list and I need to add them to shop cart. I need to add them with ajax, I did write ajax request, so how should I pass vars to ajax and then send to controller:

```
function AddToCart(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/CartNancy/Add",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            id : id
        },
        success: function () {
            prompt("Added to cart");
        }
    });
}
```

**And this is form**

```
<form method="post">
<input name="Id" value="@item.Id" class="btn btn-success" hidden>
<button onclick="AddToCart()" class="btn btn-success">Add to cart</button>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Delete(string id) {
    _bookService.Remove(id);
    return new JsonResult("Deleted");
}
```

Comment: You show url `CartNancy/Add` in frontent, but show method `Delete` in backend. Btw. what vars you'd like to pass to ajax request?

Comment: Your url is wrong. It should be "/ControllerName/Delete" or razor syntax: '@Url.Action("Controller", "Delete")'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force Web API to read the simple id from the request body, add the [FromBody] attribute to the parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Delete([FromBody]string id) {
    _bookService.Remove(id);
    return new JsonResult("Deleted");
}
```

You can check the full doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody):

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [FromBody] to the parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Delete([FromBody]string id) {
    _bookService.Remove(id);
    return new JsonResult("Deleted");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you defined the function with the id parameter but did not send it when calling. can't see add to cart function on controller.

if you want to add that hidden value to ajax request then..

```
function AddToCart() {
    var id = document.getElementsByName("id")[0].value;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/CartNancy/Add",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            id : id
        },
        success: function () {
            prompt("Added to cart");
        }
    });
}
```